# What are good tools for CRLF discovery?

Tags: web-application, xss, tools, vulnerability-scanners

What are good tools for finding [CRLF injection](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/crlf-injection/) vulnerabilities?

Comment: What's CRLF? a linebreak?

Comment: this http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/crlf-injection/

Comment: As above @user1203028 has linked, the Acunetix WVS detects them as well.

Comment: @user1203028 - I see you have a few closed questions in a row. Have you had a good read of the [faq] and the about pages? They will help you structure your questions in a way that fits better here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRLF injection can be used in [IMAP/SMTP command injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_IMAP/SMTP_Injection_%28OWASP-DV-011%29) and in [HTTP Response Splitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_response_splitting).  In both cases BURP is the tool of choice.

[Wapiti](http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/) is a FOSS vulnerability scanner that can detect http response splitting.  The vast majority vulnerability scanners should be able to detect this attack.